# Can Java reflection in Clojure be memoized?

Tags: clojure

Type-hints can make a huge improvement on execution time where reflection occurs many times. My understanding of type-hints is that it just allows the compiler to cache a reflection lookup. Can that caching occur dynamically? Or is there some reason this would be bad/impossible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Programming Clojure](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/shcloj/programming-clojure):

> These warnings indicate that Clojure has no way to know the type of
>   c. You can provide a type hint to fix this, using the metadata syntax
>       `^Class`:

```
(defn describe-class [#^Class c]
{:name (.getName c)
:final (java.lang.reflect.Modifier/isFinal (.getModifiers c))})
```

> With the type hint in place, the reflection warnings will disappear. The
>   compiled Clojure code will be exactly the same as compiled Java code.
>   Further, attempts to call describe-class with something other than a Class
>   will fail with a ClassCastException.

So to sum up, the reflection cast isn't just cached it is eliminated.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my incorrect understanding on how type hints work. I still feel the larger question about caching reflection is unanswered, but will accept that the implication is that it is not straightforward if at all possible.

Answer (score 3):

Rich was kind enough to enlighten me:
"The real answer for the JDK proper is [JSR 292](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=292), the `invokedynamic` instruction, which allows for the proper construction of call site caches with performance much better
than memoizaton."